# jquery validate names with hyphen generating errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate framework and the form that i want to validate has lots of fields with hyphens in name like retirement-age, street-name etc.

when i validate these fields like

```
rules:{
street-name:{
required:true
},
retirement-age:{
required:true
}
} // have error messages for the same.
```

these fields generate error message **Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**. I cannot change the name  of the fields as this will impact a lot of code that has already been written. Can anybody suggest an alternative.

PS: Html markup for the page is generating by CMS and hence i cannot control that. The name of the fields will always have a hyphen until i change them into the code explicitly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enclose the keys with special characters like `-` with `""` - it is not a problem with the validator but a javascript object syntax

```
rules: {
    "street-name": {
        required: true
    },
        "retirement-age": {
        required: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, i am getting this error.

**SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
 

IDM.validationRules."retirement-age"=  { required : true , aor : true };**

The parameter IDM.validationRules is dynamic and actually forms all the rules and messages in my code.

Comment: it should be `IDM.validationRules["retirement-age"]= { required : true , aor : true };` ... you need to use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)